# Check if content_object is of certain model

Tags: django, django-models, django-contenttypes

With the simplified models:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null= True)
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

How should I check whether a `Notification`'s content_object is of the `Person` class?

```
if notification.content_type:
    if notification.content_type.name == 'person':
        print "content_type is of Person class"
```

That works, but it just doesn't feel right nor pythonic. Is there a better way?

Comment: May be `notification.content_type.model` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isinstance(object, Class)` to test if any `object` is instance of `Class`.

So, in your example try this:

```
if notification.content_type:
    if isinstance(notification.content_type, Person):
        print "content_type is of Person class"
```

Answer (score 1):

With small modification to xelblch's answer: Using isinstance is a good idea, but you need to use content_object:

```
if notification.content_object and isinstance(notification.content_object, Person):
    # Your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, You may try

```
Person.__name__
```